# How to access GetSystemService(AudioService) in the UI layer

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am developing android App in Xamarin. I want to create an interface and its implementing class in the UI layer. As you see in the below code,
I am getting an error when ever, I use

```
this.GetSystemService(AudioService);
```

it is never recognized.
please have a look at the imports below. please let me know how to get it working.

**code**:

```
 public class ImplClass :   
 InterfaceFile
 {
    public bool IsAllowed(Context ctx)
    {
        AudioManager audioMgr = 
 (AudioManager)this.GetSystemService(AudioService);
     }
    }
```

**import**:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Contexts;
using Android.Media;
using MvvmCross.Platform;
using Android.Content.PM;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "Application Context".

#### Example:

```
public class ImplClass : InterfaceFile
{
    public bool IsAllowed(Context ctx)
    {
        AudioManager audioMgr = (AudioManager)Application.Context.GetSystemService(AudioService);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using this and it works.

```
global::Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService
```